# wxpython link and open new window apps

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have one dialog app and one frame app (two files) and I want them to interact with each other.

I would like to to click a button on my dialog app and it will close the dialog app and open my frame app. Any idea how I can achieve this?

my dialog app is very simple and looks something like this

```
class ThisClass(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(APP_SIZE_X, APP_SIZE_Y))

        wx.Button(self, 1, 'Start Monitoring', (50, 20), (120,-1))
        wx.Button(self, 2, 'View Data', (50, 70), (120, -1))
        wx.Button(self, 3, 'Close', (50, 120), (120, -1))


        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.idk1, id=1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.idk2, id=2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.clickClose, id=3)

        self.Centre()
        self.ShowModal()

    def idk1(self,event):
        #i want to launch another app here if 
        #this (Start Monitoring) button is pressed

    def idk2(self, event):
        self.Close(True)

    def clickClose(self, event):
        self.Close(True)

app = wx.App(0)
MyButtons(None, -1, 'buttons.py')
app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to create a frame around your Dialog app so it doesn't act strangely. No one ever said you have to Show it:

```
class ThisFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(0, 0))
        dlg = ThisClass(self, -1, "buttons.py")

        if dlg.ShowModal() == 1:
            from otherfile import MyFrame
            mf = MyFrame(self, "MyFrame")
            mf.Show()

app = wx.App(0)
frame = ThisFrame(None, 'ThisFrame')
app.MainLoop()
```

In your idk1 method, call self.EndModal(1) to return a known value. Now at some point you'll have to figure out how to cleanly Destroy your apps, but I think you can get it from here!

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. I did something similar to what you suggested, i managed to get my MyFrame (from otherfile) pop out but I can not interact with it. The widgets don't work etc

Comment: In your otherfile, make a function that does app=MyFrame(0) and app.MainLoop(), then call that function instead. That worked for me.